# I need help aligning custom sized div's

Tags: html, css

[]]]

On this URL you will see loads of "sounds" I want to get them aligned so they fit into each other is that makes sense.

like *so*

|BOX|BOX|BOX|
|BOX|###|BOX|
|BOX|BOX|###|
|BOX|BOX|BOX|
|###|BOX|###|
|BOX|BOX|BOX|
|###|###|###|
Make any sense?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, I think you are looking for something like [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/). However, I am not entirely sure what you want so I might be wrong. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks mate! What a legend!